# showDialog always returns null

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to build cusom confirmation dialog. I tried many different options, but none of them worked for me as it should

Now I have stopped at this one:

```dart
    Future<bool?> showConfirmationDialog(BuildContext context, String action, {String title = 'Confirmation'}) {
    
        bool result = false;
    
        var confirmDialog = AlertDialog(
            title: Text(title),
            content: SizedBox(
                height: 50,
                child: Text(
                    action,
                ),
            ),
            actions: [
                TextButton(
                    child: const Text("OK"),
                    onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context, true);
                    },
                ),
                TextButton(
                    child: const Text("Cancel"),
                    onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                    },
                )
            ],
        );
    
        return showDialog<bool>(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return confirmDialog;
            },
        );
    }
```

but I always get `null` in `result`:

```dart
confirmDismiss: (DismissDirection direction) async {
  var result = await showConfirmationDialog(context, 'Are you sure?');
  // here result is null always
  if (result == true){
      print('yes');
      return true;
  }
  else if(result == false){
      print('no');
      return false;
  }
}
```

How to make a confirmation dialog box in flutter correctly?

Comment: I tried your code and it worked fine. I press `OK` and received `true`.  On problem I noticed if you don't press a button but outside the dialog. The dialog will then pop too but then you will receive `null`. So you should also handle `null` in your `confirmDismiss`.

Comment: @quoci, thanks for such a quick response. I also thought at first, as you described. And I tried very hard to press the buttons). But I think I've just found the real problem: it's the context. The fact is that I passed the context to showConfirmationDialog from the item Builder of my ListView, and not from the build method of my widget, in which this ListView lay. Now I changed the context, and everything worked